# How can I use Perl to do datetime comparisons and calculate deltas?

Tags: perl, timestamp, date

I extracted year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and millisecond data from human readable text (it wasn't in a timestamp format, but rather something like "X started at HH:MM:SS.SSS on DD MMM YYYY and ended at HH:MM:SS.SSSS on DD MMM YYYY"), so for each recorded event, I have each of the values.

However, I need to turn those into some kind of timestamp so I can do math on it - I want to determine how long the event lasted (end time - start time). I was hoping the `time` function would take parameters so I can create two arbitrary `time`s, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

If possible, I would like to stick with functions available in the core Perl libraries or scripts that I can add to the project, since getting CPAN modules installed on the target machines would just make a headache for everyone, if it is even possible to get the modules through the security restrictions.

Comment: I've seen a similar question asked about one day ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365922/how-do-i-find-a-date-which-is-three-days-earlier-than-a-given-date-in-perl

Comment: @Kinopiko: you may have seen it about a day ago, but that question was asked over a month ago. (It may still be worth looking at. Just saying...)

Comment: I have to say that I don't particularly like Thomas's (or his employer's) stance towards CPAN modules, but downvotes and a close vote? WTF is going on here?

Comment: Welcome to social sites.

Comment: @Manni: agreed, especially about the close vote. There is *nothing* argumentative about this post. He wants what he wants. Votes are individual choices, but there's no reason at all to close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [Time:Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html). It's basically the reverse of the built in "localtime" function, so you can generate a timestamp from a standard date.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that `Time::Local` was bundled with Perl! Learn something new every day. +1

Comment: Time:Local looks good, but it unfortunately only has second granularity. Although I do need to look into if sec can be decimal, since I could combine sec and milliseconds into sec.milliseconds.

Comment: Well, you can always add the fractional part to the timestamp "after the fact". My testing with `mktime` also indicates a second granularity too. :-)

Comment: Yes, I could do that. Either way, this looks extremely promising. I'm going to experiment with this now and if it works, come back to accept.

Comment: One thing to be aware of, when using `Time::Local` versus using mktime, is that `Time::Local` interprets years differently to mktime. (Month is still 0-based though, i.e., 0 == January, 11 == December.) IMHO, the year handling in `Time::Local` is "too automagic", but this is a matter of personal taste. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You want the CPAN module [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/). [Here's](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=321831) an introduction.

On a Debian GNU/Linux or Ubuntu system, simply run:

```
apt-get install libdatetime-perl
```

to install the module.

Comment: No. I want to avoid installing as not all of these machines can have random CPAN modules installed on them due to security restrictions.

Comment: The DateTime module isn't exactly a "random" CPAN module. You might want to rethink either your security policy or your deadlines.

Comment: When it comes to CPAN, it has it's highs and lows. The modules that are recommended by Perl hackers themselves are often pieces of software that can be considered "trustworthy" to Perl developers on a level analogue with a peer-reviewed scientific report.

Therefore, while it is true you should be careful with CPAN, DateTime is *not* a "random" CPAN Module.

See, for example:

http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?pbp_module_recommendation_commentary
http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?recommended_datetime_modules
http://perl.net.au/wiki/Recommended_Perl_Modules#Date.2FTime

Comment: DateTime is certainly a module that is worth the effort to install.  If you have many hoops to jump through, you may wish to include some formatters (which can parse as well as format date time data). DateTime::Format::Strptime is a good one to start with.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of built-ins these may be helpful:

1. [`POSIX`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) (for `mktime` and `strftime`)
2. [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html), [`Time::Local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) and [`Time::Seconds`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html). These are all standard in Perl 5.10, but may not be available by default on earlier systems.

That said, time/date calculations are *complex*. If the only obstacle is a few headaches installing modules (rather than a company policy forbidding them), I would really recommend looking at CPAN.

**Edit**: I see from your comment on another post that there *are* company restrictions. You should update your original post, since there's a big difference between "headaches" and "security restrictions." In any case, [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) and [`Date::Manip`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date::Manip) are worth looking at. Even if you don't install them, you can get a lot out of reading their source.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what the exact policy is, but I was told to avoid CPAN modules as it would delay rolling out to some machines, at the very least, and prevent rolling out in the worst case. Security and all with unvetted software. Perl and it's core libs are vetted, so there's no problem to get Perl updated, if it needs to be.

Comment: Ok, well then definitely take a look at `Time::Piece` which has a `strptime` function that you may have use for.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: That is silly. They trust the code you give them, right? What is preventing you from copying and pasting the code in the CPAN module? What is you bundled all the libraries you wanted into a PAR file and included that with your script?

Comment: @Thomas Owens: See also http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-keep-my-own-module%2flibrary-directory%3f

Answer (score 2):

If you were only interested in comparing times,

```
my $ts1 = sprintf( '%4.4d%2.2d%2.2d%2.2d%2.2d%3.3d', 
                   $year1, $month1, $mday1, $hour1, $min1, $sec1, $ms1 );
```

to

```
my $ts2 = sprintf( '%4.4d%2.2d%2.2d%2.2d%2.2d%3.3d', 
                   $year2, $month2, $mday2, $hour2, $min2, $sec2, $ms2 );
```

using [`cmp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) would be sufficient.

To do arithmetic on these times, use [Time::Local](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Time::Local) to get seconds since epoch and then add the `$ms1/1000` to that value.

```
my $time1 = timelocal($sec1, $min1, $hour1, $mday1, $mon1, $year1) + $ms1/1000;
```

Comment: But, `cmp` won't tell you how many milliseconds elapsed between `t1` and `t2`....

Comment: That will teach me not to post an answer based solely on the title and the first paragraph. Clearly, calculating elapsed time is not a *comparison*.

Comment: Elapsed time could be considered a comparison if you look at the result. For example, a negative elapsed time means that something happened before something else.

Comment: @Thomas Owens and `cmp` will return `-1` if `$ts1` refers to a time before `$ts2`.

Comment: Title edited to make it more clear the OP wants more than a <=>-style comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `POSIX::mktime` to turn broken-up time into a timestamp. Be aware that the month is 0-based, and the year is 1900-based, so adjust accordingly. :-)

```
use POSIX qw(mktime);
$timestamp = mktime($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $month - 1, $year - 1900);
```

Comment: Although my target platform is Solaris, is this method also available on Windows? It would make my testing significantly easier, although I suppose now is as good a time as any to start using Solaris for testing and debugging of these scripts.

Comment: `mktime` is a standard C function, so it should be available on Windows too.

Comment: OK. That's what I thought, but when I see POSIX, I get worried when I am dealing with Windows. Although (according to the requirements, anyway), I don't need to run on Windows machines.